# regex in django 2.0 re_path

Tags: python, regex, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm fairly new to python and Django, so please excuse me if this seems like too simple a question.

I've been trying to use this in CreateView, but it is not working:

```
re_path(r'^<str:pk>/$', indexView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

Can anyone tell me why, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are doing wrong, you are using `re_path` which expects regex, you should use `path` here in this case. And also you should use `slug` type and not `str`.

```
path('<slug:pk>/', indexView.as_view() ,name = 'index'),
```

But if you still want to use, `re_path` you have to use regex.

```
re_path(r'^(?P<slug>\w+)/$', indexView.as_view() ,name = 'index'),
```

You can follow the [django docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/).

Comment: can you please explain what this means, (?P<slug>\w+)

Comment: It means that whatever string is passed will be stored in variable `slug` that can be accessed at time of writing views.

Comment: that didn't work, this worked, '(?P<pk>\w+)' ... no i meant how is that written, how can i understand something like that and write it by myself, without memorizing it

Comment: Coz you are referring using, variable `pk` that is also fine. but if you are giving `slug` then you need to refer using `slug` variable. it can be anything. It like giving naming to your variable.

Comment: Even with `?P<pk>\w+)` its perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing up the regular expression (`re_path()`) and converter  (`path()`) syntax. Assuming your pk is an integer you should use either:

```
path('<int:pk>/', indexView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

or

```
re_path(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', indexView.as_view(), name='index'),
```